How do I fix individual faces all having this weird shading/3D look?
Sometimes the faces of the mesh I'm working on become very odd looking.
In the picture, on the left, the mesh is as it should be. On the right, the mesh's faces are looking very weird.

They have the same exact amount of vertices, which are all in the same exact positions (relative to their origins). Both of the meshes have correct normals and are shaded flat.
What causes this to happen, and how do I fix it the correct way (and not with a tedious workaround like I did to get the left of the meshes pictured)?


Hello and welcome. Can you try go into Edit Mode and press A to select all and then Shift+N to recalculate normals. Can you also share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

@HarryMcKenzie I've already tried to recalculate normals and I did say in the post that the normals were correct. I've also posted the file just now.

well your normals are not correct. you have to Clear Custom Split Normals Data under Object Data Properties > Geometry Data tab

@HarryMcKenzie Thank you so much. I always have this problem and now finally, the solution. I appreciate this greatly :)

Click on the object on the right -> select the data tab (it looks like a triangle with 3 nodes) -> scroll down to geometry data -> clear custom split normal data -> auto smooth.
